# How to segue to a view managed by Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I am working working on an app (iOS 5+) that contains a stacks of views that are managed by a navigation controller:

MyNavController -> MyRootViewController -> MyTableViewController -> MyDetailViewController

I also have view controllers that are not managed by the navigation controller for handling the login (LoginViewController) and registration (RegViewController) of the app.

When the app is launched, it will check if an account has been created. If so, it will seque to the LoginViewController for user login, and then it will segue to MyRootViewController. However, if no login is detected, the user will be presented with the RegViewController scene to create an account. Then, I would like to take the user directly to the MyTableViewController scene, bypassing the RootViewController scene. Is this possible (via Storyboard or programatically)? I have attempted to define a modal segue from RegViewController to MyTableViewController, which seems to partially work - it is able to go to the scene but with the nav bar missing on top of screen. But when I select a table item it fails to go to MyDetailViewController. It crashes with error "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered showing the login or register view controllers as modal views from the initial view controller?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. However, for my registration process, I actually have 2 views, and my registration views are segue from my login view since I have a "Create account" button in login view that segue to reg. views: (LoginViewController->RegViewController1->RegViewController2). So if my initial view show login view using the presentViewController method, and the user ended up in RegViewController2, how do I then return back to the MyRootViewController?

Comment: The initial view controller (the one after the navigation controller) should not have any interactive UI elements (perhaps just a spinner or a splash image). All it does is connect to the server and redirect the user down the right path.

Comment: Maybe I am confused but here is what I understand based on your comments. My nav-related views setup: MyNavController -> MyRootViewController -> MyTableViewController -> MyDetailViewController. My login/reg views path: LoginViewController->RegViewController1->RegViewController2. As you suggested earlier, connect to LoginView as modal (using presentViewController method?) from MyRootViewController. (cont.)

Comment: But my current logic flow is that if certain condition in LoginViewController is met/satisfied, I would dismiss LoginViewController which should take me back to MyRootViewController. Otherwise, from LoginViewController the user will proceed thru RegViewController1->RegViewController2, and then I would like to dismiss RegViewController2 and either go back to MyRootViewController, or be able to take user directly to MyTableViewController (preferred).

Answer (score 0):

Select your MyDetailViewController. On the top select editor->embed in ->navigation controller.

Comment: I tried and it didn't help. The problem still persists and I think its because the RegViewController is not managed by an UINavigationController. So making MyDetailViewController, which is already managed by MyNavController, to be embedded in yet another navigation controller will not help. Correct me if I didn't understand your suggestion correctly.